# Excel 2010 Shapes - How to.. Size Narrowest, Widest, Tallest, Shortest... Where is the toolbar?

Tags: excel, size, alignment, shapes

In Excel 2003 and earlier.. there is an option and "tear off menu" to do
Narrowest, Widest, Shortest, Tallest.

Say.. if I select 4 different rectangle shapes of different sizes.. (multi).. and
I click... "to widest"... all the shapes will be the same size (of the widest one).

Say... if I click to "shortest"... all shapes will match to the shortest height.

--
This toolbar is not available in Excel 2010... Where to find it?

---

For your idea.. there is the Alight to Left, Right, Top and Bottom... in the Format Tab, Arrange Group.. Align (Drop Down).

---

I just need a similar one for Sizing the shapes.

Can someone help?

Excel 2003 was wonderful for this... And, with a "Tear menu" it was simply superb... and Excel 2010 is now backward.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it doesn't exist anymore [not since 2007](http://peltiertech.com/WordPress/what-happened-to-my-favorite-excel-2003-chart-feature/)

Comment: then how can we even make sure we size things correctly with a click of a button... isn't it so backward.. that we can't do this in later versions... Office 2003 rocks.. so bad with 2007/2010. Also near tear off menu.. Microsoft has lost their brain. 

(yes i know about using the physical width or height and type in the numbers, but that is no good).